# How to load API data into MYSQL database using talend

Tags: etl, talend

I am new in Talend. I want to load my api(for eg: [www.abc.com/villages/](http://www.abc.com/villages/)) data into my mysql database. How can I do it?

this is my api data:

```
{
    "message": "Resource created/Updated",
    "data": {
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 256,
                "name": "Abc",
                "createdAt": "2020-07-09 04:06:23",
                "updatedAt": "2020-07-09 04:06:23"
            },
            {
                "id": 512,
                "name": "Xyz",
                "createdAt": "2020-07-09 04:06:23",
                "updatedAt": "2020-07-09 04:06:23"
            }
        ],
        "page": 1,
        "total": 51551,            
    },
    "type": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what data you want to extract from your json and load into your MySQL table.
First, you need to flatten your json data, by using tExtractJSONFields component:
[image]

Here I'm extracting id, name, createAt and updateAt; and logging this data to console. You can replace tLogRow by the db output component.

```
.---+----+-------------------+-------------------.
|                   tLogRow_1                    |
|=--+----+-------------------+------------------=|
|id |name|createdAt          |updatedAt          |
|=--+----+-------------------+------------------=|
|256|Abc |2020-07-09 04:06:23|2020-07-09 04:06:23|
|512|Xyz |2020-07-09 04:06:23|2020-07-09 04:06:23|
'---+----+-------------------+-------------------'
```